# in ruby in windows, executing the cmd prompt command 'move' gives error "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd

in ruby in windows, executing the cmd prompt  command 'move' gives error "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

But it works outside of ruby

```
C:\rubytest>echo asdf>c:\techprogs\azzz.azz

C:\rubytest>del c:\techprogs\azzz.azz

C:\rubytest>echo asdf>c:\techprogs\azzz.azz

C:\rubytest>move /y c:\techprogs\azzz.azz c:\techprogs\autorun.bat
        1 file(s) moved.

C:\rubytest>move /y c:\techprogs\azzz.azz c:\techprogs\autorun.bat
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\rubytest>
```

All of that above is fine and expected.

Notice I never get an error that says "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Then  try in ruby

I have a simple file with one line

```
C:\rubytest>type syntaxcommandincorrect.rb
`move /y c:\techprogs\azzz.azz c:\techprogs\autorun.bat`

C:\rubytest>
```

But it gives that error about the syntax

```
C:\rubytest>del c:\techprogs\azzz.azz

C:\rubytest>ruby syntaxcommandincorrect.rb
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\rubytest>echo asdf>c:\techprogs\azzz.azz

C:\rubytest>ruby syntaxcommandincorrect.rb
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\rubytest>
```

Comment: Remember inside of backticks backslashes have special meaning and need to be escaped. Consider: `move /y c:\\techprogs ...`

Comment: @tadman thanks, that's probably it, I'll check back when I get back to that computer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is probably the backslashes which have significant meaning inside of interpolated Ruby strings, double-quoted but also backtick-style shell commands.

As such your command is being interpreted as:

```
move /y c:^Iechprogs^Gzzz.azz c:^Iechprogs^Gutorun.bat
```

Where `^I` is `"\t"` which is a tab character, and `^G` is `"\a"` which is a [bell character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character).

Instead:

```
`move /y c:\\techprogs\\azzz.azz c:\\techprogs\\autorun.bat`
```

Now remember that Ruby has a very comprehensive library of functions you can use to address this directly. Don't treat it like a fancy shell scripting language:

```
require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.mv('c:\techprogs\azzz.azz', 'c:\techprogs\autorun.bat', force: true)
```

Where here I'm using single quotes to avoid the double backslashes and `force: true` is the equivalent of `/y`. This uses [`FileUtils.mv`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/FileUtils.html#method-i-mv), part of a whole package of useful file and directory manipulation utilities.

As a plus you also get proper exceptions if something goes wrong, or an error code if the move failed.

**Added by barlop**

Confirming the above.  Double backslash fixes it, and i see via doing puts `echo copy /y c:\techprogs...` what happens with single backslash, I see the t of techprogs removed, as `c:\techprogs` became `c:<ascii-9>echprogs.`  And `\autorun` became `<ascii-7>utorun`

```
C:\rubytest>cmdoutoutwithoutinitbat.rb | xxd
0000000: 6162 6364 6566 670d 0a63 6f70 7920 2f79  abcdefg..copy /y
0000010: 2063 3a09 6563 6870 726f 6773 0775 746f   c:.echprogs.uto
0000020: 7275 6e2e 6261 7420 633a 0965 6368 7072  run.bat c:.echpr
0000030: 6f67 7307 7a7a 7a2e 617a 7a0d 0a61 6263  ogs.zzz.azz..abc
0000040: 6465 6667 0d0a 6d6f 7665 202f 7920 633a  defg..move /y c:
0000050: 0965 6368 7072 6f67 7307 7a7a 7a2e 617a  .echprogs.zzz.az
0000060: 7a20 633a 0965 6368 7072 6f67 7307 7574  z c:.echprogs.ut
0000070: 6f72 756e 2e62 6174 0d0a                 orun.bat..

C:\rubytest>
```

Comment: I will test this re backslash. But that wouldn't explain why this in ruby gives no error ``copy c:\techprogs\azzz.azz c:\techprogs\autorun.bat``  Also, doing `move /y c:^techprogs^azzz.azz c:^techprogs^autorun.bat` in the cmd prompt says `The system cannot find the file specified.`  it doesn't say anything about a syntax error

Comment: The `^I` and `^A` is for illustrative purposes only and is not actually something you'd type in.

Comment: You can also try `system('move', '/y', 'c:\techprogs\azzz.azz', 'c:\techprogs\autorun.bat')` with a `system` call having separate arguments, but honestly using `FileUtils` is better for a multitude of reasons.

Comment: well what is ruby sending to cmd that gives that syntax error then?

Comment: Try with `echo` instead to see.

Comment: ok , thanks, that shows it, it's doing tab.. BTW, the reason why I am using shell commands, is because ultimately i'll be using a command to set the command prompt. like `prompt $P$G` or in linux  `export PS1=\w $`  that kind of thing

Comment: I see what you mean.. I get an ascii 9 in the first case(with missing t), and an ascii 7 in the second case(with missing 'a') .  So  `\t` became replaced with ascii 9, maknig `c:\tech`  into   `c:<tab>ech`  and simiilar in the scond case,   `\auto` became `<ascii 9>uto`

Comment: That's what the [tab character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters) is, ASCII 9. `"\a"` is actually `^G`, or the ["bell" character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character), ASCII 7, and often makes your terminal beep, and apparently dates from 1870.